# Xamarin Android HeartRate Sensor Activation

Tags: android, xamarin, heartrate

I want to make a simple App for my Samsung Watch 4 Wear OS but I'm struggle to get the sensor for the heart rate up an running in my xamarin android solution.

What I tried so far is:

'''

```
        using Android.Hardware;

        SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)this.GetSystemService(SensorService);
        if (sm.GetSensorList(SensorType.HeartRate).Count != 0)
        {
            Sensor s = sm.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.HeartRate);
            sm.RegisterListener(this, s, SensorDelay.Fastest);
        }
```

...

```
        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
           // Do something...
        }
```

'''

But I think I have to activate/start the sensor itself first but how?
I tried with the Android emulator and with the smart watch device but no luck.

I'm working with VS2022 / API Level 31.

Thanks for some hints!

Comment: checkn the  return value of  RegisterListener which whether the sensor is supported and successfully enabled or not.

Comment: The return value is always false... So no change to get the heart rate sensor working? Maybe another lib?